# How many times does the derivative of this function meet the x=0 line?

Tags: calculus

How many times does the derivative of the following function meet the x=0 line?
f(x)=$\left(x+1\right)\left(x-0.7\right)\left(x-e\right)\left(x-\pi \right)$.
I know they meet exactly 3 times, and I know how to explain they meet at most 3 times, but explaining why they meet *exactly* three times is where I'm having trouble.

Answer (score 3):

$f(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $4$ with $4$ real roots. Order them $x_1<x_2<x_3<x_4$. Then the derivative must vanish at least one time in each interval $(x_i,x_{i+1})$. Since it cannot vanish more than 3 times (the derivative is a polynomial of degree 3) it must vanish exactly 3 times.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Calculate the derivative, and draw the graph of $f'$. If you can find $4$ points $x_1<x_2<x_3<x_4$ for which 
$$f(x_1)<0\\
f(x_2) > 0\\
f(x_3) < 0\\
f(x_4) > 0$$
Then the mean value theorem implies that $f'$ has at least $3$ roots.